# Accessing the music files in iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I need to build a system which backup and restore system in which all the phone datas 
including audio, video, pictures. From iPhone 4.0 , there is support for accessing the videos 
and photos from the library . Is there any way to access the music files. I need to convert those music files into binary format . Is there any way to accomplish this...

awaiting for the response

Best Regards,
Mohammed Sadiq.

Comment: iphone 4.0 is still under NDA

Answer (score -1):

Mohammed,

Please see the Add Music example on Apple's website:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/AddMusic/Introduction/Intro.html

-Rob

Comment: Hi rob,

  Thanks a lot. I have already gone through the link . But no where in that example as 
well as in MediaPlayer.framework, there is no option to get the bytes of the music files . Is there anyway to get the bytes of music files ?